# Why is my recursive binary search function not returning anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return

(...don't ask about the array values, they're Latin American food brands that became inside jokes with some friends).

```
def binSearch(arr, i, lower=0, upper=None):
    if upper is None:
        upper = len(arr)+1
    idx = (lower+upper)//2
    if arr[idx] == i:
        print(idx, arr[idx],'\n')
        #return idx
    elif arr[idx] != i and upper-lower<2:
        print("Not found \n")
        #return False
    elif arr[idx] < i:
        print(idx, arr[idx])
        binSearch(arr, i, idx, upper)
    elif arr[idx] > i:
        print(idx, arr[idx])
        binSearch(arr, i, lower, idx)

myArray = ["Chabona", "F-Nandito VII", "La Bichy", "Manaos", "Martín y Enzo", "Pitusas", "Trompis", "Ugi's", "VAMOS MANAOS", "Villamanaos"]

binSearch(myArray, "Manaos")
binSearch(myArray, "Coca-Cola")
```

This programme does exactly what I expected it to do – it outputs this:

```
5 Pitusas
2 La Bichy
3 Manaos 

5 Pitusas
2 La Bichy
1 F-Nandito VII
Not found
```

However, this is what I get when I comment out all the print statements to have it return `idx` or `None` instead, and then replace the calls with `print(binSearch(myArray, "Manaos"))` and `print(binSearch(myArray, "Coca-Cola"))`:

```
None
None
```

It's obviously supposed to return `3` and `False` but it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning:

```
return binSearch(arr, i, lower, idx)
```

You also need to return in your conditions:

```
def binSearch(arr, i, lower=0, upper=None):
    if upper is None:
        upper = len(arr)+1
    idx = (lower+upper)//2
    if arr[idx] == i:
        print(idx, arr[idx],'\n')
        return idx # return 3/idx
    elif arr[idx] != i and upper-lower<2:
        print("Not found \n")
        return False  # return False
    elif arr[idx] < i:
        print(idx, arr[idx])
        return binSearch(arr, i, idx, upper)
    elif arr[idx] > i:
        print(idx, arr[idx])
        return binSearch(arr, i, lower, idx)

print(binSearch(myArray, "Manaos"))
print(binSearch(myArray, "Coca-Cola"))

5 Pitusas
2 La Bichy
3 Manaos 

3
5 Pitusas
2 La Bichy
1 F-Nandito VII
Not found 

False
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! If I understood right, this means my recursive calls were running the function but since they didn't return the value it didn't 'reach' the main call, doesn't it?

Comment: You were not returning anything so like any other function if you don't specify a return value it will return None by default .

Comment: python tutor is helpful to see what is happening http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display